# Using a part of a class in multiple projects

Tags: c#, refactoring, partial-classes

I have a set of methods that do some utility work over SQL connection, and until now these have been copied over from project to project. But as time goes on, project numbers have grown and I need to keep these methods in sync in case I find a bug or need to update it.

I have managed to get it to the state that SQL access class is a **partial** class, one part is specific for project and contains wrappers for a specific database. The second part is the common one and contains methods that are used in all project-specific databases.

The problem is that now I would have the "utility" class copied over 8 projects, with the same content, but in different namespaces. In C/C++ it would have been simple, because I would just have #included the contents of the file wherever needed. What should I do in C#?

Comment: Question: why not make from the class a utility library with all the project linking to it? If you need project specific implementation then you can provide methods/hooks for customization in your utility library (like overridable methods) - inherit from this class in your projects and implement/override the methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate out the class so that you can have a complete class containing all of the common code, in a common project. Use a common interface to represent the bits of functionality which will be project-specific, implementing that interface in each project and passing an instance of the interface into the common code where necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why separating it this way didn't occur to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Jon says, a library assembly is a good idea.

There are some situations when an assembly reference doesn't lend it self to the requirements so, if creating a library assembly is not an option, it is possible to use a feature easily overlooked in Visual Studio, [adding an existing file as a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx).

This would allow you to maintain the common part of the partial class in a file that is available in all your projects.

The only restriction is that a relative path is used to reference the file.

The only problem I have had with this strategy is with the open source Mercurial scc provider. When removing a linked file from a project, the underlying file is deleted. Quite annoying but this may not be an issue for you.

Update: The linked file bug in the [VS Mercurial SCC](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html) should be fixed in the next release.